# Windows 2012 R2 Firewall Rule apply only after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server with firewall activated and inbound connections in blocked by default.

When i create a rule A to open port 5060 UDP to any source and then create a rule B to block all inbound trafic from a specific IP (207.182.146.146), the blocking rule B is applied only after a system restart.

If i modify the IP or add another IP to the scope of rule B, it's applied only after a restart.

Does anyone knows how i can modify rule's scope and block trafic without restarting the hole server ?

OS Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
OS Version: 6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
Running on an ESXI 6.5 host

Comment: Have you tried restarting the firewall service?

Comment: You might also try restarting the service that is listening on the port.  Or blocking both inbound and outbound traffic instead of just inbound.

Comment: Yes, i tried restarting the firewall service and the dependencies. Restarting the service listening on the port 5060 UDP is not an option (current SIP calls will be dropped)

Comment: Have you tried blocking outbound traffic as well as inbound traffic for the remote IP address?  Inbound rules don't normally apply if there is outbound traffic to the same address and port (because it is a stateful firewall) but an outbound block rule might override that.